# Error al guardar datos en tabla SQL

Tags: sql, .net, framework, core

Tras estar probando y mirando diferentes errores que iban apareciendo, he conseguido conectar a una base de datos y aparece el siguiente error al intentar guardar datos en la tabla:

[image: Error gráfico]

Cadena Error
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Usuario_dbo.Banco_BancoID". The conflict occurred in database "TimeBankConecction", table "dbo.Banco", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.

La configuración de tablas es la siguiente:

```
USE TimeBank

CREATE TABLE Banco (
ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
NOMBRE varchar(100) NOT NULL,
EMAIL nvarchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Usuario (
ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
NOMBRE varchar(100) NOT NULL,
APELLIDO varchar(200) NOT NULL,
USUARIO nvarchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
CLAVE nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
EMAIL nvarchar(255) UNIQUE,
BancoID int,

CONSTRAINT FK_BancoUsuario 
    FOREIGN KEY (BancoID) 
    REFERENCES Banco(ID)
);

INSERT INTO Banco(NOMBRE, EMAIL)
VALUES('BANCO PEREZ', 'informacion@bancoperez.com')
```

Edito con dos capturas más demostrando que no es ése el error: con usuario 2, ingresando servicio con esa ID, persiste el fallo:

[image: Ingresamos servicio]

[image: Error]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo debe ir como texto, y el error tambien.. y el error es claro, estas ingresando un codigo de banco que no esta en la tabla bancos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te dice el error es que quieres ingresar en tu tabla `Usuario` un registro con 1 como valor de `BancoID` pero en tu tabla `Banco` no existe el registro con
ese valor de `id`
Revisa tu base de datos y checa que `id` tiene `BANCO PEREZ`.

> ### **Foreign Key Constraints**
>
> A foreign key (FK) is a column or combination of columns that is used to establish and enforce a link between the data in two tables to control the data that can be stored in the foreign key table.
> [Microsoft doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#FKeys)

Como dice el texto anterior. Los `Foreign Key` son columnas para hacer cumplir la relación entre dos tablas.
Estás estableciendo la relación de la tabla `Usuario` en su columna `bancoID`  con el `id primario` de la tabla `Banco`.
SQL lo que hará cada que quieras crear un registro en usuario con cualquier `bancoID` será revisar si en la tabla `Banco` existe algún registro con ese `id primario`; de no existir te tira ese error `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint`.

Comment: Buenas tardes Alejandro. Gracias por tu ayuda, lamentablemente no parece ser el caso, he adjuntado nuevas capturas con más detalle.

Comment: @Angelrat pues la tabla que debes revisar es BANCO porque es donde te están diciendo que el ID buscado no corresponde al que intentas insertar (y tampoco nos estás mostrando qué datos intentas insertar)

Comment: ¿Tienes registros en tu tabla banco?. ¿Podrías mostrar una captura de una consulta a esa tabla?